# Two ways of getting logged in user claims - which is better?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Recently, I've encountered such a problem - two properties of the same name (User) and return type, seemingly doing the same, reside in two different namespaces :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.User

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.User
```

The only description VisualStudio gives me says that one of them is associated with current request, second - with current action.

In this bit of code I'm trying to get name of currently logged user. They both give the same result.

```
var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
model.Username = username;
var username2 = User.Identity.Name;
model.Username2 = username2;
```

They seem very similar. Can you tell me in what cases should I use each of them?

Comment: You should change a bit your question, asking that is opinion based, if you instead ask about the differences it will be better fitted for S.O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [ASP.NET Core source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L195), the `ControllerContext.User` property is just a shortcut to the `HttpContext.User` property:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the <see cref="ClaimsPrincipal"/> for user associated with the executing action.
/// </summary>
public ClaimsPrincipal User => HttpContext?.User;
```